# Concourse CI telia-oss/github-pr-resource stops working

Tags: pull-request, concourse, concourse-resource-types

We are using a GitHub PR resource in one of our Concourse pipelines that works for a while, then completely stops picking up new commits, except for one bizarre situation: one user is able to push commits to the repo that get picked up immediately, while commits from anyone else are seemingly ignored.

The resource is a black box in terms of its functionality, because it doesn't seem to log its activity or provide any way to enable that logging.

We've opened a PR with the maintainer of resource: https://github.com/telia-oss/github-pr-resource/issues/298

Are there any ways to troubleshoot this issue, or determine what its query is and what results it's seeing when it decides there are no new commits?